# How to setup Canon wireless printer on Linux

Tags: networking, printer, canon

A new Canon PIXMA TS6250 has wifi interface to setup and apps to set it up via wifi network but none of them are for Linux. In the process of first seting up, the printer creates its own access point, and while connecting to it gives you an address and is then responding to ping at 192.168.114.1 and obviously runs a webserver or some app on https://192.168.114.1/

Since there is no app for linux, is there a way to set it up anyway without using Mac or Windows?

It probably needs to be setup to connect to a local router and then it most probably should work as a network printer. I just can't figure out how to configure it for wifi.

Comment: Looks like it can also be configured using an Apple or Android smartphone - do you have one of those available?

Comment: have you tried connecting to https://192.168.114.1/ with a browser?

Comment: @telcoM yes, i actually solved it with an app on a android tabled, but it doesn't solve the question - how to configure it via linux machine only.

Comment: @cas yes, it gave me a 404 error.

Comment: @luka i recommend taking it back for a refund because it's broken, and getting something known to work with open, well-documented networking standards (like dhcp).   there was no warning before you bought it that it required you to run spyware on a phone or on a windows or mac box, was there?

Comment: Looks like Canon has decided that setting the WiFi parameters is "too hard to get right" for their average customer, and so they've made their product rely on an app that simplifies the process. Unfortunately, those apps exist only for Mac, Windows and Apple & Android smartphones. The printer supports Apple AirPrint, so the https service is probably actually an IPP service, with some vendor-specific extensions for configuring the printer... but since the exchange is TLS encrypted, reverse-engineering it would be non-trivial.

Comment: After I have setup the wifi on the printer the administration interface is available at https://IP.OF.THE.PRINTER/rui/ - perhaps this helps someone. I have not yet tested if I go back and try to reset the printer into AP mode and try the /rui/ url on it.